# HTML can not load jquery.js from server

Tags: jquery, html, tomcat

I have put my `jquery-2.1.0.min.js` in `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\Restful\lib`, but when i refresh my app, it can not load the resource, it gives a `404` Not Found error instead.

I also try to directly access the resource in `http://localhost:8080/Restful/jquery-2.1.0.min.js`; same error.

Here is my html file:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <base href="<%=basePath%>">
    <title>My JSP 'success.jsp' starting page</title>
    <script src="/lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Success!</p>
    <c:forEach var="i" items="${currentTask}">
        <p><c:out value="${i}"></c:out></p>
    </c:forEach>
    <div id="label"></div>
    <form:form action="/Restful/vacationRequest/checkInTask" method="POST">
        <input id="getPi" type="button" value="Get Process Instants"/>
        <input value="Next Task" type="submit"/>
    </form:form>
    </form>
    <script>
        $("#getPi").on("click",function(){
                    $.ajax({url:"localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/process-instances",
                    username:"kermit",
                    password:"kermit",
                    type:"GET",
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#label").html(result);
                    }});
            });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try removing the '/' from the request -- `<script src="lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to your library is `/Restful/lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js`. The path you're using in your script tag starts with a `/` so the browser is looking in `/lib/...`.

Your HTML document is in `/Restful`, so you can either omit the leading `/` from the path in your script tag so that the browser starts its search from the current folder, or use `/Restful/lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js`

Comment: not working but omit the leading "/" and in the browser i use link http://localhost:8080/Restful/lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js not working too

Answer (score 0):

> `url:http://localhost:8080/Restful/lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js`

you did leave lib/ path on jquery link

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could just link to the jquery source page

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```